# .htaccess - URL amigable afecta rutas de imagenes y js

Tags: .htaccess

Les explico:

Mi web sin URL amigables es asi

**httpx://dominio.com/?loquesea=valor**

y mis imagenes y js funcionan perfecto

**src="img/imagen1.png"**

**src="js/script.js"**

El error viene cuando tengo URLs amigable

**httpx://dominio.com/loquesea/valor**

Pues el DOM me toma las rutas de las imagenes y js asi:

**httpx://dominio.com/loquesea/valor/img/imagen1.png**
**httpx://dominio.com/loquesea/valor/js/script.js**

Obviamente da el error.

y se como solucionarlo poniendo la URL de la web. o poniendo ../../

Pero la cosa no es alli´
Ya me cansé de que en cada proyecto sea igual.

ASI QUE BUCO LA SOLUCION CON HTACCESS PURO.
Alguien me puede ayudar?

**PD: Quiero que se puede lograr relativamente, ya que este script se instala en varios dominios y no quiero estar configurando URL para cada dominio diferente.**

**Este es el codigo que tengo en mi htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# idiomas web.com/es/   web.com/en/   web.com/br/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/?$ index.php?lang=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Algo así para evitar que un directorio se traslade:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/.*$
```

Sería mejor si pones el contenido de tu .htaccess actual en tu pregunta.

Edit: ya veo, es más complicado de lo que pensaba. Puedes hacer algo así:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.+/(img|js)/(.+)$
RewriteRule . /%1/%2 [R]
```

Cualquier URL que contiene `/img/` o `/js/` es redirigido hacia `/img` o `/js` más el resto.  Así que:

```
httpx://dominio.com/loquesea/valor/img/imagen1.png
httpx://dominio.com/loquesea/valor/js/script.js
```

se vuelven:

```
httpx://dominio.com/img/imagen1.png
httpx://dominio.com/js/script.js
```

Comment: agregue el código amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es poner rutas absolutas, y para que te valga para varios dominios, es obtener el nombre de dominio con php. Ejemplo:

```
$nombreDominio = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Y para poner las rutas asi:

```
src="<?php echo $nombreDominio; ?>/img/imagen1.png"
```

Espero que te sirva